# How to give source and destination path for imagemin in node js

Tags: node.js, server, mean-stack, gulp-imagemin

I have gone through this

There the code appears like this

```
const imagemin = require('imagemin');
const imageminMozjpeg = require('imagemin-mozjpeg');
const imageminPngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');

imagemin(['images/*.{jpg,png}'], 'build/images', {
    plugins: [
        imageminMozjpeg({targa: true}),
        imageminPngquant({quality: '65-80'})
    ]
}).then(files => {
    console.log(files);
    //=> [{data: <Buffer 89 50 4e …>, path: 'build/images/foo.jpg'}, …] 
});
```

I am not sure tat where should I need to give the source folder path and where should be the destination path.Can anyone help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've found the answer yourself by now, but just to not leave this thread void:

the source path would be replacing this part **['images/***
whereas **'build/images'** would be replaced by the desired destination path.

Answer (score 0):

2020 and this solution doesn't work anymore, here is the code that they provided in the library:

```
let files = await imagemin(['yourSourceFolder/*.{jpeg,png,jpg}'], {
        destination: 'yourDestinationFolder',
        plugins: [imageminMozjpeg({quality: 10})]
    });
    console.log("image minified")
    console.log(files)
```